# Emacs wrapping lines that are exactly 80 characters long in a 80x24 terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs

Using a 80xN terminal, I'm seeing that lines that are exactly 80 characters long are wrapped and the 80th character is shown on a separate line:

[image: wrapping]

Is there some way to stop emacs from wrapping lines that are *exactly* 80 chars long? (Or rather, exactly `$COLUMNS` long?). And show them on one line while still wrapping lines that are > 80 chars long... After all, they *do* in fact fit on an `$COLUMNS` wide terminal.

A [2003 posting](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2003-10/msg00715.html) on help-gnu-emacs says:

> Also, prior to Emacs 21, Emacs wasted a column for the "\" character that's
>   used to indicate that a line has wrapped (Emacs 21 replaced this with a
>   marker closer to the window border).  So a line that's exactly the window's
>   width would be wrapped -- the first n-1 characters would be on the line,
>   then there would be a "\", and then the next line would contain the nth
>   character.

Which describes my situation perfectly, except I'm running Emacs 24.4.1 according to `(emacs-version)`.

(I'm investigating returning to Emacs after many years with Vim. And yes, I want to run Emacs in the terminal, as 99% of my development time I'm editing on remote servers)

Comment: Emacs has support for editing remote files using `tramp`, so you could run a local emacs under a windowing system.

Comment: Note that "closer to the window border" isn't actually possible in a terminal.  That text is describing how in GUI frames the fringe is now used to avoid unnecessary wrapping in such situations.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with all the mechanisms involved here, but I can see in the documentation that the continuation marker can be a character defined by the *display table*, and that there is `zero-width` character display option for *glyphless characters*.  It's possible (although I'm not at all certain) this would successfully hide the continuation marker -- however I'm not seeing an obvious way to do so contextually.

Comment: Assuming it's not supported, it seems like a reasonable feature request.

Comment: Following on from @phils comment, the following sets the line continuation character to a zero width space, so lines that are exactly 80 characters long are displayed without a continuation. Unfortunately lines longer than that get truncated `(let ((disptab (or buffer-display-table
                   (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table)))))
    (set-display-table-slot disptab 'wrap (gethash "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" (ucs-names))))`

Comment: @rpluim: When I try your `(let...)`, I get this in `*Messages*`: `set-display-table-slot: Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, (("BELL (BEL)" . 7) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-256" . 917999) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-255" . 917998) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-254" . 917997) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-253" . 917996) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-252" . 917995) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-251" . 917994) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-250" . 917993) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-249" . 917992) ("VARIATION SELECTOR-248" . 917991) ...`

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten that ucs-names used to be an alist. Try this instead `(let ((disptab (or buffer-display-table
                   (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table)))))
    (set-display-table-slot disptab 'wrap (cdr (assoc "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" (ucs-names)))))`

Comment: @rpluim: Thanks yes I see. Sorta works, but doesn't wrap long lines, so I would've been better off with `toggle-truncate-lines`, which also is not what I want.

Comment: I don't think there's a good solution for what you want in `-nw` mode